# Function pointer works regardless of signature? Surprise

Tags: c++, events

I was implementing a small library for testing purposes an learning about event handling and declaring events in standard C++.

After some time of struggling and debugging my creatures, I finally got it work!!

Here is sample code after all:

```
#include "Event.h"
#include "Handler.h"
using namespace System;  // lol yeah, I wrapped all into namespace called System (like .NET) :D

//this is the actual event trigger function:
int x(int) {
    Write "event!!";
    return 0;
}
    typedef void (*EventHandler)();  //this is funny( pointer to int(*)(int)


//simple implementing new keywords: (macros and typedefs)

int main() {
    event test;  //new event
    Handler hnd(test, EventHandler(x));  // EventHandler takes void(*)() NOT int(*)() !!!
    emit(test);  //raise event triggers the x function with no problem
    return 0;
}
```

How come it compiles with no error??

I would paste all the code but it's complicated...

My question is: I'm confused how `typedef` of `EventHandler` works just fine?

Compile output is just fine and there is no error no matter what the signature of the "event trigger function".

Comment: `EventHandler(x)` is the same as `(EventHandler)x`. You're forcing the compiler to treat `x` as a different type, why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: *"I would paste all tHE code but it's complicated"* - more useful to both readers and yourself would be to construct a minimal, complete example. From the code you've shown it looks like you'd only need to supply a stub for `Handler` and drop the `event` stuff.

Comment: @ildjarn That’s the answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ildjarn, OH great, yeah that's the answer. but one more thing: Is that safe? forcing the compiler to threat calback function differently? what are possible side effects? thanks alot :D

Comment: @codekiddy No, it’s not safe. The result is completely undefined and won’t work in general. The morale here is never to use this style of cast, because it can blow up so easily without detection.

Comment: are you kidding us? of course it is not safe. The possible side effects range from SEGFAULT to psychedelic colorful patterns on your screen.

Comment: I'm glad you got your answer, but I don't believe this question will help other users in the future. :(

Comment: @vdbuilder don't say twice. always someone find some post useful. thanks for help to all.

Comment: @codekiddy Not necessarily, sometimes the scope of the situatation is so narrow that it is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
EventHandler(x)
```

Is a cast operation:

It is syntactically equivalent to:

```
((EventHandler)x)
```

So you are using the cast operator to cast x (int (*)(int)) in-to an EventHandle (void (*)())

Cast operations are done without warning because you are basically telling the compiler:
`"I know better than you what is actually going just believe me OK!"`.

The underlying emit() is then just calling the function pointed to without any parameters.
This is bad.

The function X() is expecting a parameter that is not there. depending on the ABI the called function may tidy that up (which is probably not good), luckily X does not use the parameter as that would be undefined as-well.

The function X() is supposed to return a value (not doing so is undefined behavior). Yet the calling function is not expecting a returned value so doing so would be undefined behavior as depending on the ABI you may be overwriting important data.

Comment: thank's for answer, it was informative for my situation.